# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" error after Angular page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Sorry if this is a simple problem, I am a newbie to angular and trying to integrate it as a front end for a basic rails blog app. I am a bit stuck on a problem that I think is related to angular promises, but not sure. I am getting the following error in the console after a page refresh:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at Object.$scope.prepArticleData
```

I have an articleData service which loads all the table data fine when I point the url to the ArticleIndex page and also loads individual articles when a link is clicked on the Index page. However, when I refresh an individual article page in the browser the currentArticle object data is lost and the data is instead replaced in the view with the angular curly braces. I have googled it quite a bit but can't seem to find the reason why it breaks. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Article service

```
angular.module('app').factory('articleData', ['$http', ($http) ->

articleData =
data:
  articles: [{name: 'Loading', content: ''}]
isLoaded: false

articleData.loadArticles = (deferred) ->
if !articleData.isLoaded
  $http.get('./articles.json').success( (data) ->
    articleData.data.articles = data
    articleData.isLoaded = true
    console.log('Articles loaded successfully.')
    if deferred
      deferred.resolve()
  ).error( ->
    console.error('Failed to load articles.')
    if deferred
      deferred.reject('Failed to load articles.')
  )
 else if deferred
    deferred.resolve()

articleData.createArticle = (newArticle) ->
# Client-side data validation
if newArticle.newArticleName == '' or newArticle.newArticleContent == ''
  alert('Neither the Title nor the Body are allowed to be left blank.')
  return false

# Create data object to POST
data =
  new_article:
    name: newArticle.newArticleName
    content: newArticle.newArticleContent

# Do POST request to /articles.json
$http.post('./articles.json', data).success( (data) ->

  # Add new article to array of articles

  articleData.data.articles.push(data)
  console.log('Successfully created article.')

).error( ->
  console.error('Failed to create new article.')
)

return true

return articleData

])
```

Article controller

```
@ArticleCtrl = ($scope, $routeParams, $location, articleData) ->

$scope.data =
articleData: articleData.data
currentArticle:
  name: 'Loading...'
  content: ''

$scope.data.articleId = $routeParams.articleId

articleData.loadArticles()

$scope.prepArticleData = ->
article = _.findWhere(articleData.data.articles, { id: parseInt($scope.data.articleId) })
$scope.data.currentArticle.name = article.name
$scope.data.currentArticle.content = article.content


$scope.prepArticleData()

@ArticleCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'articleData']
```

This route is set up in the routeProvider to load currently selected article into the mainArticle view:

```
 when('/article/:articleId', { templateUrl: '../assets/mainArticle.html', controller: 'ArticleCtrl' }).
```

The mainArticle view:

```
<h2 class="text-left">{{ data.currentArticle.name }}</h2>
<div class="">
<p>{{ data.currentArticle.content }}</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="editPost()">Edit</button>
</div>
```

It seems like the prepArticleData function must be called in the ArticleCtrl when page is refreshed, and the  relative articleId passed through again from the url but I have no idea how to do it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like that the async call `articleData.loadArticles()` does not complete before you call `$scope.prepArticleData()`

This causes the `findWhere` to return nothing and the next lines fail

You should call `$scope.prepArticleData()` on the promise success callback.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it didn't fix the problem. I tried adding the call to prepArticleData after "console.log('Articles loaded successfully.')" as well as after "deferred.resolve()" in the ArticleData service but just got more errors. Maybe I am putting the call in the wrong place?